# detecting different ajax request to same file

Tags: jquery, ajax, request

i have two forms, which i validate and send to same page, after which i need, for each request, my response is different from the php file. so my question, how to i find the differnt ajax request. i tried

```
if(isset($_SERVER['HTTP_X_REQUESTED_WITH']) && !empty($_SERVER['HTTP_X_REQUESTED_WITH']) && strtolower($_SERVER['HTTP_X_REQUESTED_WITH']) == 'xmlhttprequest')
```

but this works for all request..

```
      $(document).ready(function(){
$("#form1").validate({
     debug: false,
rules: {

passwordid:"required",
username:"required",
password_again :"required",
password_again:{
  equalTo: "#passwordid"
},
 email: {
 required: true,
 email: true
}
 },
messages: {

email: "Please enter your valid email address.",
username: "Please enter your username",
passwordid:"Enter Password",
password_again:"Please enter the same value",
},
  submitHandler: function(form) {

$.ajax
({
type: "POST",
url: "action.php",
data: $('#form1').serialize(),
cache: false,
success: function(html)
{

    $(".result").prepend(html);





  }
        });
    }
    });

$("#form2").validate({
     debug: false,
rules: {

datepicker:"required",
hourid1:"required",
minuteid1:"required",
dhour:"required",
dminute:"required",
   },
messages: {

datepicker:"Please enter your date",
hourid1: "Enter your time",
minuteid1:"Enter your time",
dhour:"Enter your duration",
dminute:"Enter your duration",
 },
  submitHandler: function(form) {

  $.ajax
  ({
  type: "POST",
  url: "action.php",
  data: $('#form2').serialize(),
  cache: false,
  success: function(html)
  {

   $(".result1").prepend(html);





}
        });
    }
});
});
```

i just need a simple way to identity my ajax request..any help appreciated.. Thanks in advance.. And sorry if this happens to a stupid question...

Comment: check referer or add param eq action.php?id=form1

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Just add a hidden input with a given name to each form, but with different values, and when serialized and sent you'll access that on the serverside :

```
if ( $_POST['myFormsName'] == 'form1' ) {

}
```

Answer (score 1):

Why not just pass an additional parameter indicating which form generated the request?  This could easily be achieved by adding a hidden input field on each form with some sort of identifier the server could use to distinguish forms.